# Odd behaviour with np.fft.fftfreq and np.where

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I noticed the following behaviour when playing around with `np.fft.fftfreq` and `np.where` :

```
k_array = np.fft.fftfreq(100)
k_array = k_array/k_array[1] #Normalizing the array for my purposes

for k in range(20):
  print(np.where(k_array == k))
```

I get the output as :

```
(array([0]),)
(array([1]),)
(array([2]),)
(array([3]),)
(array([4]),)
(array([5]),)
(array([6]),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([8]),)
(array([9]),)
(array([10]),)
(array([11]),)
(array([12]),)
(array([13]),)
(array([], dtype=int64),)
(array([15]),)
(array([16]),)
(array([17]),)
(array([18]),)
(array([19]),)
```

why is it not giving any output for the values at 7 and 14? It also skips over 28 and 29.

P.S. If I pass in the iterator as `k_array`, it works as normal. It also exhibits normal behaviour if I pass in an iterator obtained from using `np.linspace`, i.e. `m_array = np.linspace(0.,100.,101)`

Comment: `where/nonzero` finds the `True` elements of its argument. Look at `k_array == k`.  My guess is `k_array` is floats, and the match isn't close enough for those `k`.  `np.isclose` is a better test with floats.